# Readability and Performance of my Trie implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, trie

As an interesting exercise in Python 3.3, I implemented a [**Trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (also known as a Prefix Tree).

### Example usages

#### Create from list of key-value-tuples

```
mapping = (('she', 1), ('sells', 5), ('sea', 10), ('shells', 19), ('today', 5))
trie = Trie.from_mapping(mapping)
some_prefix = 'sh'
some_key = 'today'

print('Keys:', *trie)
print('Items: ', *trie.items())
print('Keys prefixed "{}":'.format(some_prefix), *trie.keys(prefix=some_prefix))
trie[some_key] = -55
print('Value of "{}":'.format(some_key), trie[some_key])
print(some_key, 'is in' if some_key in trie else 'is not in', 'the Trie')
```

> **Output**
>
> ```
> Keys: today sells sea she shells
> Items:  ('today', 5) ('sells', 5) ('sea', 10) ('she', 1) ('shells', 19)
> Keys prefixed "sh": she shells
> Value of "today": -55
> today is in the Trie
> ```

#### Find out lengths of words in a string

```
words = 'She sells sea shells today she sells no shells she sells'.split()
trie = Trie.from_keys(words, value_selector=len)
print(*trie.items())
```

> **Output**
>
> ```
> ('sells', 5) ('sea', 3) ('she', 3) ('shells', 6) ('today', 5) ('no', 2) ('She', 3)
> ```

---

### Implementation

For simplicity, each entry is represented by a `dict` mapping characters to child entries – if this is problematic, feel free to remark on that.

```
class _Entry:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.children = {}

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.children.items())
```

I made it iterable so I don't have to constantly write things like `entry.children.items()`.

Here's the `Trie` itself – please feel free to **point out any or all issues you can spot.** I started taking a look at Python two weeks ago, so I'd also appreciate your comments on how Pythonic (or not) this is, as well as any potential issues of performance.

```
class Trie:
    @staticmethod
    def from_mapping(mapping):
        """
        Constructs a Trie from an iterable of two-item tuples.
        :param mapping: An iterable of key value pairs (each key must itself
        be an iterable)
        :return: A new Trie containing the keys and values in the mapping
        """
        trie = Trie()
        for key, value in mapping:
            if not key:
                continue
            trie[key] = value
        return trie

    @staticmethod
    def from_keys(keys, value_selector):
        """
        Constructs a Trie from an iterable of keys, mapping each key to the
        value returned by the value selector function, which is passed each key.
        :param keys: an iterable of keys (each key must itself be an iterable)
        :return: a new Trie containing the keys in the mapping
        """
        trie = Trie()
        for key in keys:
            if not key:
                continue
            trie[key] = value_selector(key)
        return trie

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Creates an empty Trie.
        """
        self._root = _Entry()
        self._length = 0

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
        Gets the value corresponding to the specified key.
        :param key: an iterable
        :return: the value corresponding to the key if it is in the Trie,
        otherwise None
        """
        entry = self._find(key)
        if entry is not None:
            return entry.value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """
        Sets or inserts the specified value, mapping the specified key to it
        :param key: an iterable to update or insert
        :param value: the object to associate with the key
        """
        self.update(key, lambda old_value: value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        """
        Removes the value of the specified key without removing it from the Trie
        :param key: the iterable whose value is to be removed
        """
        self[key] = None
        self._length -= 1

    def __contains__(self, key):
        """
        Determines if the key is in the Trie and has a value associated with it
        :param key: the iterable to search for
        :return: True if the Trie contains the key, otherwise False
        """
        entry = self._find(key)
        return entry is not None and entry.value is not None

    def __len__(self):
        return self._length

    def __bool__(self):
        return len(self) > 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.keys())

    def keys(self, prefix=''):
        """
        Searches for keys beginning with the specified prefix
        :param prefix: an iterable
        :return: A generator yielding the keys one by one, as they are found
        """
        yield from (key for key, value in self.items(prefix))

    def items(self, prefix=''):
        """
        Searches for key value pairs where the keys begin with the specified
        prefix
        :param prefix: an iterable
        :return: A generator yielding tuples of keys and values as they are
        found
        """
        start = self._find(prefix)
        if start is None:
            return ()
        stack = [(prefix, start)]
        while stack:
            current_prefix, entry = stack.pop()
            if entry.value is not None:
                yield current_prefix, entry.value
            for char, children in entry:
                stack.append((current_prefix + char, children))

    def update(self, key, value_selector):
        """
        Updates key with the value obtained from the value selector function,
        to which the old value corresponding to the key is passed.
        :param key: the key whose value is to be updated
        :param value_selector: a function that takes the old value as an
        argument and returns a new value
        """
        entry = self._root
        for char in key:
            if char not in entry.children:
                entry.children[char] = _Entry()
            entry = entry.children[char]
        new_value = value_selector(entry.value)
        if entry.value != new_value:
            entry.value = new_value
            self._length += 1

    def _find(self, key):
        entry = self._root
        for char in key:
            if char not in entry.children:
                return None
            entry = entry.children[char]
        return entry
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 1. Bug

1. Sometimes the `_length` attribute is updated wrongly. First, when deleting an item, the length is decremented regardless of whether the item was actually present in the trie:

   ```
   >>> trie = Trie()
   >>> del trie['key']
   >>> len(trie)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ValueError: __len__() should return >= 0
   ```

   Second, when updating an item, the length is incremented regardless of whether the item was actually new:

   ```
   >>> trie = Trie()
   >>> trie['key'] = 1
   >>> trie['key'] = 2
   >>> print(*trie)
   key
   >>> len(trie)
   2
   ```

#### 2. Other comments

1. You have docstrings for all your methods: awesome! You might consider adding a docstring for the `Trie` class (look at the output of `help(Trie)` and consider what else is needed). This is also a good class to consider adding [doctests](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).
2. Since the class `_Entry` is only used in `Trie`, you could make it an attribute of `Trie`.
3. In the `_Entry` class, you use `None` as a placeholder to mean that there is no value associated with this entry. This prevents anyone from storing `None` as a value in a `Trie`. Instead, you could leave the `value` attribute unset to indicate no value (this can be detected with the [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) function), and write `del entry.value` to delete it.
4. You could have `_Entry` inherit from `dict` and then you wouldn't need to have an attribute `children`.
5. By using [`@staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) you prevent anyone from subclassing `Trie`, because when someone calls `SubTrie.from_mapping`, the object they get back will be a `Trie` rather than a `SubTrie`. You should use [`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) instead:

   ```
   @classmethod
   def from_mapping(class_, mapping):
       trie = class_()
       # ...
   ```
6. It's not clear why you have the lines:

   ```
   if not key:
       continue
   ```

   in `from_mapping` and `from_keys`. Why can't I add the empty string to a `Trie`? (If you have a good reason, it would be worth mentioning it in the documentation, and also worth raising an error here, instead of silently discarding these keys.)
7. The `__getitem__` method returns `None` to indicate failure. In Python it's normal to raise an exception to indicate failure rather than returning an exceptional type. In this case it would be appropriate to raise `KeyError` (just as the built-in `dict.__getitem__` does).
8. You might consider whether `Trie` should inherit from [`MutableMapping`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) in the [`collections.abc`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) module: this would give you `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `pop`, `popitem`, `clear`, `update` and `setdefault` methods for free.
9. Since your `Trie` class presents a mapping-like interface, Python programmers will expect its `update` method to present a similar interface to the [`update`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method on ordinary dicationary objects. (This is easy if you inherit from `MutableMapping` since the `update` method is defined in that abstract base class.)

   (Your original `update` would then need a new name.)
10. Similarly, since your `Trie` class presents a mapping-like interface, Python programmers will expect its constructor to present a similar interface to the [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor. (Again, this is easy if you inherit from `MutableMapping` since you can just pass the positional and keyword arguments to the `update` method.)
11. It seems perverse that the `value_selector` argument to the `update` method is different from the `value_selector` argument to the `from_keys` method. (The former takes the *old value* as its argument but the latter takes the *key* as the argument.) This can only be confusing to users.

    Also, if your `update` method is called, but there's no value in the trie for `key`, the `value_selector` function gets called anyway (with the argument `None`). You might consider whether this method should take a third argument, the value to use in the case where there is no value in the trie. (Or maybe you should raise `KeyError` in this case.)

    I have a feeling that your `from_keys` and `update` methods are not very Pythonic. Instead of `from_keys`, callers would be happy to write:

    ```
    Trie((key, f(key)) for key in keys)
    ```

    and instead of `trie.update(key, lambda old_value: old_value + 1)` caller would be happy to write

    ```
    trie[key] += 1
    ```

    My guess is that your goal in writing the `update` method is to avoid the double lookup in the above. So it's a reasonable thing to provide, it just needs some thought about the name and interface.
12. You could simplify some of your logic if your `_find` method was able to create new `_Entry` objects. See below for how.
13. If your function body consists only of `yield from <generator>`, you might as well write `return <generator>`.

#### 3. Revised code

This is how I would write the class, addressing all the points above.

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class Trie(MutableMapping):
    """
    A prefix tree.

    >>> mapping = dict(she=1, sells=5, sea=10, shells=19, today=5)
    >>> trie = Trie(mapping)
    >>> some_prefix = 'sh'
    >>> some_key = 'today'
    >>> print(*sorted(trie))
    sea sells she shells today
    >>> print(*sorted(trie.items()))
    ('sea', 10) ('sells', 5) ('she', 1) ('shells', 19) ('today', 5)
    >>> print(*trie.keys(prefix='sh'))
    she shells
    >>> trie['today'] = -55
    >>> trie['today']
    -55
    >>> len(trie)
    5
    >>> 'shells' in trie, 'shore' in trie
    (True, False)
    >>> del trie['shells']
    >>> len(trie)
    4
    """

    # A dictionary with an optional :value: attribute.
    class _Entry(dict):
        def has_value(self):
            return hasattr(self, 'value')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Return a new True initialized from an optional positional
        argument and a possibly empty set of keyword arguments, as for
        the built-in type :dict:
        """
        self._root = self._Entry()
        self._length = 0
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
        Gets the value corresponding to the specified key.
        :param key: an iterable
        :return: the value corresponding to the key if it is in the Trie,
        otherwise raise KeyError.
        """
        entry = self._find(key)
        if entry.has_value():
            return entry.value
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """
        Sets or inserts the specified value, mapping the specified key to it
        :param key: an iterable to update or insert
        :param value: the object to associate with the key
        """
        entry = self._find(key, create=True)
        if not entry.has_value():
            self._length += 1
        entry.value = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        """
        Removes the value of the specified key from the Trie
        :param key: the iterable whose value is to be removed
        """
        entry = self._find(key)
        if entry.has_value():
            del entry.value
            self._length -= 1
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._length

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.keys())

    def keys(self, prefix=''):
        """
        Searches for keys beginning with the specified prefix
        :param prefix: an iterable
        :return: A generator yielding the keys one by one, as they are found
        """
        return (key for key, value in self.items(prefix))

    def items(self, prefix=''):
        """
        Searches for key value pairs where the keys begin with the specified
        prefix
        :param prefix: an iterable
        :return: A generator yielding tuples of keys and values as they are
        found
        """
        try:
            start = self._find(prefix)
        except KeyError:
            raise StopIteration
        stack = [(prefix, start)]
        while stack:
            current_prefix, entry = stack.pop()
            if entry.has_value():
                yield current_prefix, entry.value
            for char, children in entry.items():
                stack.append((current_prefix + char, children))

    def _find(self, key, create=False):
        entry = self._root
        for char in key:
            if char in entry:
                entry = entry[char]
            elif create:
                new_entry = self._Entry()
                entry[char] = new_entry
                entry = new_entry
            else:
                raise KeyError(key)
        return entry
```

#### 4. Algorithmic concerns

1. You create `_Entry` objects for all elements in each key, even if there are no other keys sharing any of those entries. For example, if I create an empty `Trie` and then add a value for the key `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious`, 34 `_Entry` objects will be constructed, and when I look up this key, all 34 of them will have to be traversed. You might consider storing the tail of a key differently when it doesn't need to share space with other keys, and creating `_Entry` objects dynamically as necessary when you add new keys that share a prefix with existing keys.
2. When you delete keys, you don't remove `_Entry` objects that have become empty as a result. This means that later lookups may need to descend deeper into the trie before discovering that the key is not present.

Comment: Awesome! My only issue is that I sternly disapprove of the suggesting to subclass `dict` for the `_Entry` class.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Can you explain your concern?

Comment: Gareth, thank you for your outstanding review. I particularly like the way you got rid of the duplicated logic by introducing the `create` parameter in `_find`, though I think I might make it keyword-only.

Comment: It only makes sense to subclass `dict` if you are making some kind of special `dict`. Here you are creating a class which uses a `dict`, and I think thats much more naturally represented using composition rather then inheritance. I'll admit, its a bit a purest thing here.

Answer (score 3):

A note on terminology: a *mapping* is, according to [Python glossary](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping),

> A container object that supports arbitrary key lookups and implements
>   the methods specified in the Mapping or MutableMapping abstract base
>   classes. Examples include `dict`, `collections.defaultdict`,
>   `collections.OrderedDict` and `collections.Counter`.

Your `from_mapping` assumes a different type of argument.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good point. In fact, I was confused by [the `dict` constructor documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) but that's because I didn't read it carefully enough. Any suggestions for a better name? I'm thinking of `key_value_pairs`...

Comment: @codesparkle, I'd go from `from_pairs` myself.

Comment: @codesparkle I'd follow Gareth's suggestion and have the constructor call `update`.

Answer (score 2):

`__getitem__` returns None if a key cannot be found, to follow python conventions it should raise KeyError.

Simliar with `__delitem__`, I'd expected a KeyError if deleting a non-existent element.

I wonder if it would be better to have your `_Entry` object support a .items() method which could then be implemented recursively.

Given that it act a lot like a mapping, I'd expect the `update` method to act like `dict.update` but it doesn't.

```
    if entry.value != new_value:
        entry.value = new_value
        self._length += 1
```

Its not clear to me that this is the correct logic for incrementing the length.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent points. You're right about `length`: it is indeed a bug.